# Rotating 2D world within Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, game-physics

I am looking at developing a game within Unity by using C#
The game will take the gyroscope orientation and rotate accordingly to the direction of which the phone is rotated.

I am curious of how this would work, I understand how I would be able to read and update the gyroscope orientation however I am unsure on how to assign this to a world to rotate. There will be a player on world which will be the next challenge to prevent the player clipping through the world when it is rotated.
Hence the world should rotate around the players current location.

**I currently have no code as I am in the process of designing this, however i am unable to get the logic of how to make this work within my head**

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your objective right, I guess rotating the camera like in a Fist-Person game should be enough, and would be way simpler than rotating the whole world while keeping the player static.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about it, first I wouldn't rotate the world, as that is alot of objects to rotate, but if you really wanted to you could parent all of the world to a single game object, then rotate that object about an axis based off of the players position(See this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html).

The simplest way is to attach your main camera to your player(Drag and drop it on your Player Object in your hierchy), then rotate your player.

for an example you can test on your machine without the gyroscrope:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class rotatorScript: MonoBehaviour {
    void Update() {
        // Will Rotate based off of left/right arrows
        float rotator = -Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        // Move up or down based off of up/down Arrows
        float verticalDirection = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        // Do the actual movement... using space.self so it is based on the player not the world.
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * verticalDirection * Time.deltaTime * 5f, Space.self);
        transform.Rotate(0f,0f,90f * Time.deltaTime * rotator); 
    }
}
```

This script would be attached to the player.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I have not attempted this yet but the theory of this method seems correct and much more sensible to do. Following on from this, the reason I was going to rotate the world is so that gravity is always facing towards the bottom horizontal axis of the screen. Therefore, would it be possible to orientate the direction of gravity within rigidbody for example to follow the bottom of the screen?

Comment: @Roodolpha you can modify the gravity in unity based off of your characters down direction.